# Two dates in one column / stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, stored-procedures

I think this may be easy, but in my stored procedure i want to merge two date fields. They look like this:

- From_Date: 2014-01-01
- To_Date: 2014-01-31

I tried this:

```
    SELECT (start_date and End_date) 
       AS 'Sales Period'
```

and this:

```
    SELECT (start_date, End_date) 
       AS 'Sales Period'
```

But its not working. 
I want the result to be like one of these:

- Sales Period: 2014-01-01, 2014-01-31
  or
- Sales Period: 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-31
  or even better:
- Sales Period: January 2014 or:
- Sales Period: 01 2014

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast them to a string and concat them - something like this:

```
SELECT
   'Sales Period' = CAST(start_date AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' to: ' + 
                    CAST(end_date AS VARCHAR(20))
```

If you need more control over the format of the conversion, look at `CONVERT` function (instead of `CAST`) - you'll find details in the [CAST and CONVERT topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in MSDN